# What is the operation through which a Coset is created?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, set-partition, quotient-group

Most books initially explain Cosets in terms of $\mathbb{Z}$ & then use the subgroup $n\mathbb{Z}$ to partition into $n$ Cosets.

1. Is the group $\mathbb{Z}$ used here the additive $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or is it the multiplicative $\mathbb{Z}^*$? I think it's $\mathbb{Z}^*$ but want to be sure.
2. What is the operation $n\mathbb{Z}$ here? Is it the multiplication of each element of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $n$ or adding the element $n$ times?
3. What is the abstraction of the operation $n\mathbb{Z}$ in groups other $\mathbb{Z}$ or other number groups? If there is some other kind of group which doesn't involve numbers, how do you do the operation corresponding to "$n\mathbb{Z}$" in that group to create cosets?

---

UPDATE to my question:

I am using Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Gallian. He has a list of properties of Cosets.

One of the properties is

- For a group $G$ & a subgroup $H$, $aH = H$ if $a \in H$ - i.e. you generate a new coset only if $a$ doesn't belong to $H$.

The proof of this is that if $a \in H$, then a * h for each $h \in H$ generates an element of $H$ because of closure in $H$. However if H were an additive group then a*h is not an operation of H & hence why would there be closure. Hence I am assuming that H is a multiplicative group.

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z}$ are multiples of $n$ (so each element is multiplied by $n$, or added $n$ times to $0$, which is the same). It is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, and a normal one since the integers group is abelian, so one can quotient by it and get $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ to get a new group, the group of integers mod $n$. The name of the operation you're after is "quotienting". The cosets are elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $n\mathbf Z$ is not an operation, but the ideal of multiples of $n$, and the group $\mathbf Z$ is the additive group. If it were the multiplicative group of non-zero integers, you would have the star in the notation. The ‘abstraction’ is simply the quotient of a group modulo a subgroup. If the subgroup is normal, you obtain another  group.

Comment: @Bernard - For a group G & a subgroup H, the proof of "aH = H iff $a \in H$ uses the fact that H has closure for proving it. But if G & H were additive groups, then the closure would be irrelevant to the proof because a * h for all $h \in H$ is not an operation of the group - a * h is a multiplication operation.

Comment: @user93353:  I didn't say that in the abstract case, we have $aH=H$. The equivalence relation is not defined in that way. B.t.w., what do you call the closure of a subgroup?

Comment: @Bernard - you didn't say $aH = H$ iff $a \in H$-I am talking about all books which define this as one of the properties of cosets.

Comment: `what do you call the closure of a subgroup?` - I don't understand the question - it would also be called closure right? Without closure, it wouldn't be a group at all in the first place

Comment: What wouldn't be a group? $H$?

Comment: Yes, H, the subgroup of G wouldn't be a group at all if it didn't have closure

Comment: But neither the integers nor the non-zero integers form a group under multiplication, so how could it possibly be that? But in general, I agree, people in this forum frequently refer to structures related to ${\mathbb Z}$, ${\mathbb Z}_n$, etc without saying what operation they have in mind, which is irritating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Most books initially explain Cosets in terms of $\mathbb{Z}$ & then use the subgroup $n\mathbb{Z}$ to partition into $n$ Cosets.
>
> 1. Is the group $\mathbb{Z}$ used here the additive $\mathbb{Z}^+$ or is it the multiplicative $\mathbb{Z}^*$? I think it's $\mathbb{Z}^*$ but want to be sure.

The group is $\mathbb{Z}^+$, as $\mathbb{Z}$ under multiplication does not form a group. (Hint: What should the identity for $\mathbb{Z}^*$ be? Then what is the inverse of $2$, say? [Alternative issue: the element $0$.])

> 2. What is the operation $n\mathbb{Z}$ here? Is it the multiplication of each element of $\mathbb{Z}$ by $n$ or adding the element $n$ times?

This is the set $\{nx\mid x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, i.e. all multiples of the integer $n$. It is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, which is important because we need normal subgroups to form quotient groups.

> 3. What is the abstraction of the operation $n\mathbb{Z}$ in groups other $\mathbb{Z}$ or other number groups? If there is some other kind of group which doesn't involve numbers, how do you do the operation corresponding to "$n\mathbb{Z}$" in that group to create cosets?

The $n\mathbb{Z}$ sets are important here because they are *precisely* the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$. That is all that is going on.

In the general situation, any subgroup $H$ of a (multiplicatively-written)* group $G$ has cosets
$$G/H=\{gH\mid g\in G\}.$$
(We actually talk about "left" and "right" cosets, $gH$ and $Hg$, but lets ignore that here.)
Cosets are especially important as if the subgroup $H$ is a "normal" subgroup, so has the additional property that $g^{-1}Hg=H$ for all $g\in G$, then $G/H$ forms a group. This is the case with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, as every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is normal (because it is abelian).

*Groups are typically written with a multiplicative operation. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is written additively. Here, your cosets are $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{a+n\mathbb{Z}\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

---

Response to the update: As your group is additively-written, "closure" becomes $a+h\in H$. The operation $∗$, which we call "multiplication", denotes an *abstract* group operation, but when dealing with concrete groups you need to replace it with the relevant operation. Addition here, function composition for permutation groups, etc.

So we can translate Gallian to use additive notation:

> - For a group $G$ & a subgroup $H$, $a+H = H$ if $a \in H$ - i.e. you generate a new coset only if $a$ doesn't belong to $H$.

> The proof of this is that if $a \in H$, then $a+h$ for each $h \in H$ generates an element of $H$ because of closure in $H$.

Comment: One of the properties of cosets is for a subgroup H or group G, $aH = H$ if $a \in H$. The book I am referring to proves this by saying that if $a \in H$, then a when multiplied by any element of H would generate another element of H because of closure property of H. However, this would be true only if H is a multiplicative group & not an addition group because $ah$ is a multiplication operation.

Comment: @user93353 As your group is additively-written, "closure" becomes $a+h\in H$. The operation $*$, which we call "multiplication", denotes an abstract group operation, but when dealing with concrete groups you need to replace it with the relevant operation. Addition here, function composition for permutation groups, etc.

Comment: For generating $Z/nZ$ we actually "multiply" n with each element of Z to first get $nZ$ - so it's an actual multiplication & not just an abstract group operation

Comment: @user93353 $n\mathbb{Z}$ is way of writing a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ - it *just so happens* that all subgroups have the form $n\mathbb{Z}$, so people write them like this. Because they can. You can call them $H$ if you like, and your cosets are $H, 1+H, 2+H, \ldots$ instead of $n\mathbb{Z}, 1+n\mathbb{Z}, 2+n\mathbb{Z}, \ldots$.

Comment: I am talking how the normal subgroup is created - it's created by multiplication i.e. H here is $nZ$ like say $5Z$ - it's created by multiplication & not by addition.

Comment: @user93353 Right, so the point is that if $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ then it is cyclic, generated by a single element, say $n$ (this is a standard result, and will be in Gallian somewhere - but the element $n$ is simply the $\gcd$ of all elements on $H$). As $H$ is cyclic with generator $n$, the subgroup $H$ is precisely the set $\{nk\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which we call $n\mathbb{Z}$. It is just a fluke that subgroups have this form, and there is no analogue in general groups.